# android service thread process

Tags: android, multithreading, service, process, ocr

From my research I believe that their are 3 ways you can run a service in Android:

1. In the main thread of the application.
2. In a thread separate from the main thread of the application.
3. In a completely separate process.

My goal is to make an app that has the feature of running OCR against a picture and return the text. I know option 1 is out because my prototype takes a long time to run the OCR on a phone with a dual core CPU. I was not able to find discussion on this topic of threading vs. a different process for a service.

So what are the pro/cons of options 2 and 3?

Edit: I will likely use an IntentService because I want the service to terminate once it gives me the text from the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From my research I believe that their are 3 ways you can run a service in Android:

No, there are two, what you have as #1 and #3. A service can *start* a thread, but all lifecycle methods of the service are on the main application thread. Hence, #1 and #2 are the same thing, from a component architecture standpoint.

> So what are the pro/cons of options 2 and 3?

Option #3 wastes CPU and RAM for little added value, IMHO.

> I will likely use an IntentService because I want the service to terminate once it gives me the text from the image.

`IntentService` [automatically provides you with a background thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

Comment: I will use the IntentService because I have no reasons to have the service run after the app is killed and as you said a separate process will be more expensive to run.